# One to One correspondence between vertices of two graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Is it necessary that in two undirected graphs if we need to prove that vertices have one to one correspondence  then graph should have same number of edges?
What about same number of degree?

Can anyone give me a example when one to one correspondence exist without same number of edges?

How about these graphs - do they have one-one correspondence just because they have same number of vertices?

EDIT: Please note I am only looking for ONE-ONE correspondence and NOT Isomorphism

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do *you* mean by one-to-one correspondence, if not isomorphism?

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused here too. I was reading this research paper. Please see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577893/what-is-the-meaning-of-saying-two-graph-vertices-are-in-correspondence

Comment: Ahh, this is an entirely different question.  In this case, yes, the vertices are given a one-to-one mapping; they have some identity beyond mere labels.  They might represent communication peers, for instance—that's what they mean by one-to-one correspondence: Given a node representing a peer in one graph, we know which node represents that peer in the other graph.  The paper is, presumably, interested in the differing levels of connectivity presented to those peers by various network topologies.  Interesting question, but not really related to the notion of correspondence in graph theory.

Comment: And now you see why giving context is so important on Math SE. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, these graphs are not isomorphic.  It is not sufficient that there be an equal number of nodes, or even an equal number of nodes and edges.  There must exist (at  least) one bijective mapping from $G(V, E)$ to $G'(V', E')$ such that two nodes $v_1, v_2 \in V$ are connected by an edge $e \in E$ *if and only if* the corresponding nodes $v'_1, v'_2 \in V'$ are connected by an edge $e' \in E'$.

Comment: I am not asking isomorphic but only one-one correspondence. 
I think there is a difference between the two correct?

Comment: What does it mean to have one-to-one correspondence *in a graph* specifically, if the edges don't come into play at all?  What is the property that you need to establish?  I think, by and large, readers would expect one-to-one correspondence to mean more than simply "same number of nodes".

Comment: In other words, if you just mean "same number of nodes", then just say that.  If you mean "same number of nodes and edges", then say that.  Very few people, I suspect, would call either of those any kind of one-to-one correspondence.  Note that both Nick Peterson and I interpreted your question in the same way.